# How to get request content in python that supposed to be get by HttpServletRequest.getReader()?

Tags: java, python, servlets

Here is the original client code in java:

```
protected StringBuilder doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = req.getReader();
    StringBuilder reportBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String tempStr = "";
    while((tempStr = reader.readLine()) != null){
        reportBuilder.append(tempStr);
    }
    return reportBuilder
}
```

However, my client is implemented in Python, i have tried to get the content through request.POST and request.GET, none of them gets anything, i'm not a java expert, so actually i'm kind of confused here, so how to write this client code to catch the request content in python, PLEASE help me.